# Removing words from a string applescript

Tags: string, macos, applescript

I have a string "remind me to eat dinner at 5:30"
I need to remove every word before "to" and every word after "at" 
I already wrote a script to get the word number of them toNum and atNum
I can't figure out how to do this any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another approach:

```
set originString to "remind me to eat dinner at 5:30"

set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, {"to ", " at"}}
set resultString to text item 2 of originString
set text item delimiters to TID
```

Comment: Thanks that worked but now im trying to do it where the sentence is reversed i.e. remind me at 5:30 to eat dinner

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
set originString to "remind me to eat dinner at 5:30"
set resultString to text toNum thru atNum of originString
```